# Telerik for Winforms grid reordering only works visually

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I'm using a Telerik for WinForms RadGridView, I set the datasource to a custom list of objects and I enable the columnreordering. It works fine on the frontend, but if I go to select a row and read a value, it returns the vaule of the initial ordering not the actual one I see on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all 3rd party grid controls (not just WinForms) don't manipulate the underlying data source when sorts, column reordering, filter etc. are done on them.  These are just display only features.

You should just read the column value via the key not index so that it will never matter what order the user puts a column in.

Comment: Ho can i get the key or a field into the row if the rowindex doesn't match the real index?

Comment: You can use the GridViewSelectedRowCollection to get the row(s) that the user has selected and then do something like gridRow.Columns.Name = "key string name";  There is a field on the Column object for you to name the column.  There is also a field on the Column object called FieldName which is the name of the data field it is bound to.